# Добавление валидатора к стандартной аутентификации

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

1. Нужно добавить валидатор email к стандартной аутентификации. При этом не внося правки в vendor и не используя наследование.
   Есть стандартная аутентификация с коробки. У нее в трейте к `LoginController` идет метод `ValidateLogin` и в нем идет `$this->username() => 'required|string',`. Нужно добавить валидатор `email`
2. К правилу валидации email нужно добавить проверку на сторонние домены - где зарегистрировать/прописать правило, чтобы его в валидации можно было указывать как `'domain'` вместо `new Domain()`

Comment: есть стандартная аутентификация с коробки. У нее в трейте к LoginController  идет метод `ValidateLogin` и в нем идет `$this->username() => 'required|string',`. Нужно добавить валидатор `email`

Comment: По второму - где зарегистрировать/прописать правило, чтобы его в валидации можно было указывать как `'domain'` вместо `new Domain()`